# VS2012 - free less support other than Mindscape Web Workbench or Web Essentials 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less

I need syntax highlighting and compilation for LESS, but Web Essentials 2012 has just dropped their LESS editor (and the compilation has broken for me as well) and Mindscape Web Workbench only turns into a complete solution after dropping ~AU$40.

LESS is a fairly common technology for web development these days and I would expect to have VS support it without paying extra money.

Are there any free solutions out there which can provide this support for free?

To be clear, this is the required functionality:

- LESS syntax highlighting
- LESS (to CSS) compilation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes ...Web Essentials 2012 + Web Tools 2012

..actually Web Essentials dropped syntax support because now it's completely built into VS2012

http://vswebessentials.com/

Comment: you still need to keep web essentials for compilation/bundling support, or can use chirpy for that too if you prefer

Comment: Second link broken